# PHP array to JSON.parse javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have two pages, first one is index3.php and it has an action page that's called itemAction.php that handles querying from the DB and return an echo of json_encode

What I'm looking for is how to access the returned JSON array below. My itemsAction.php returns the below:

```
[{"0":"3","prod_id":"3","1":"red flower","prod_name":"red flower","2":"natural flower","prod_dtl":"natural flower","3":"1500","prod_price":"1500","4":"2","Cateogry_cat_id":"2"},{"0":"4","prod_id":"4","1":"blue flower","prod_name":"blue flower","2":"natural flower","prod_dtl":"natural flower","3":"1500","prod_price":"1500","4":"2","Cateogry_cat_id":"2"},{"0":"5","prod_id":"5","1":"yellow flower","prod_name":"yellow flower","2":"natural flower","prod_dtl":"natural flower","3":"1500","prod_price":"1500","4":"2","Cateogry_cat_id":"2"},{"0":"6","prod_id":"6","1":"white flower","prod_name":"white flower","2":"natural flower","prod_dtl":"natural flower","3":"1500","prod_price":"1500","4":"2","Cateogry_cat_id":"2"}]
```

Here's my index3.php

```
<?php
include("dbh.php");
?>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="bin/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    //practice onchange
    window.onload = function (){
    var onChange = document.getElementById("selection");
    onChange.addEventListener("change", change);
    function change(){
        var selectedItemso = document.getElementById("selection");
        var catValue= selectedItemso.options[selectedItemso.selectedIndex].value;
        var url = "itemsAction.php?cat=" + catValue;
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', url, true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                findoutLoaction(xhr.responseText);
            }
        }
        xhr.send();
    }
    function findoutLoaction(data) {
       var json = JSON.parse(data);
       var address = json.myArray[1].prod_name; // Here's the I have an issue
       alert(address);
       targetLoc.innerHTML = address;
    }
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="comments">
    <hr>
    <div id="selectOptions">
    <select id="selection">
        <option value="1">Food</option>
        <option value="2">Flowers</option>
        <option value="3">Clothes</option>
        <option value="4">Toys</option>
        <option value="5">Perfoume</option>
    </select>   
    </div>    

    </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Better to comment it out rather than adding `** **`!

Comment: What is the issue you're having?

Comment: Why do you have `myArray` in there?  That's not in your json anywhere.  Should simply be `json[0].prod_name`

Answer (score 0):

You already have your data. You should be able to iterate through the array with a for...in somehow like this:

```
for (var key in json) {
    console.log("key: " + key);
    console.log("array item:" + json[key]);
}
```

Insert this code instead of your ** .. ** line. You can use your array like any associated array in php.

Answer (score 0):

you JSON structure is wrong i think.

{ .. } is object,
[ .. ] is array,

so in your json, [ {...}, {...}, {...}, {...} ] is an array of 4 objects without key, can be reached by index.

within each object, you are using keys correctly, but naming is wrong maybe. you have:

{0:"3"

1:"red flower"

2:"natural flower"

3:"1500" 4:"2"

Cateogry_cat_id:"2"

prod_dtl:"natural flower"

prod_id:"3"

prod_name:"red flower"

prod_price:"1500"}

left is key, right is value

then you have: json[0].prod_name gives you first prod name "read flower", and so on.